# wordpress database import issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theming

After I have made a database export in phpMyAdmin, and replaced the old URL with new URL, I have issues with importing of wordpress website's database. After database import, my website still display front page in default mode, default posts, default settings, some default texts and images, even some plugins not working exactly same as before Export and Import of this database.

I tried to export and save my website's database from phpMyAdmin panel. Then I deleted all tables with data. When I tried to export database before deleting, I remember that, I have selected some export options like:

Export method: Custom

Format: SQL

Tables: All structure and data

Save output to a file

Format-specific options: Display comments, Enclose export in a transaction

here is the beginning of the export file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Aug 18, 2017 at 12:06 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.36-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

**NOTE:**
**I have replaced some words from saved database file, it is the new URL of the website, something like this:
www.mywebsite.com/somefolder/  with  www.mywebsite.com**

Please help me to fix this issues and import correctly my database table's structure and data from the saved export file.

I hope it is possible to fix it...

Comment: Have you confirmed that the issue is with the database? Is the data fo the posts etc in the tables or are they missing? Have you ruled a problem with the WP settings e.g. wp_config, or security plugins such as iThemes Security?

Comment: @ FluffyKitten yesm that issye is with the database, I think it is caused after I have replaced some words from database export file, it is the old URL replaced with new URL

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using the duplicator plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure, it is not late ? because I already did export, then deleted, then imported the database from export file. What I can do not, is delete again and import again the saved file

Comment: This is a commenr